# Adding a button to align with ttk notebook caused a geometry problem

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have found out a method to get a button to align with ttk.Notebook.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
ttk.Button(notebook).pack()
notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
label = ttk.Label(notebook, text='Text', font='Arial 50')
notebook.add(label, text='Tab')
root.mainloop()
```

However, this caused a problem that the geometry manager only displays the button. I have to maximise the window in order to see all the contents.
In my another bigger gui, this is just a little bit of the window. I can’t see the content inside the notebook even I maximise the window.
So, how can I get it working? Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you're calling `pack` on a button inside the notebook. The button is empty so it has a size of zero, and calling `pack` on the button causes the notebook to shrink to the size of the button.

You shouldn't ever call `pack` or `grid` on widgets that are direct children of a notebook, they should only ever be added with the `add` method of the notebook.

It's not clear where you want the button, but it shouldn't be a child of the notebook. If you make it a child of the root window (eg: `ttk.Button(root)`, you can add it to the root window with `pack` to get it to be either above, below, or to one of the sides of the notebook.